# from solidity: TypeError: Expression has to be an lvalue. --> contracts/mytoken.sol:18:27: |18 | for(i; i <=10000; totalSupply++)

Tags: solidity

```
// contracts/mytoken.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract mytoken is ERC20 
{
    address public owner_ = msg.sender 

    constructor(uint256 totalsupply, uint256 decimals) ERC20("INTERFORM", "INTRN") {
        
        totalsupply = totalsupply**decimals;

        _mint(msg.sender, totalsupply);
    }

    function forfun(uint256 i) public{
        for(i; i <=10000; totalSupply++)
        {

            return balanceOf[owner_] = totalSupply;

        }
    }

    
}
```

why doesnt my code not work

basically im getting my total supply and all the other functions inhereted from ecr20 but i was testing if i could for loop to add total supply everytime i increases and then get the balance of the owner. how could i fix my code

Comment: Please, can you explain better your forfun() login function?

Comment: it increases the amount  of the totalsupply by one then each time it does that the balance of the owner becomes equal to the totalsuppply